# Why smarty greater than function doesn't work?

Tags: php, css, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have tried to insert the following code to alternate the CSS style from my Add to Cart button on my online store, so when the product are 0 that need to display "Order" instead product are greater than 1 that need to display "Add to Cart", but the class .hideen (with the greater than >= ) doesn't work instead the other one yes..

```
{if $product->quantity <= 0}
<style type="text/css">
{literal}
.hideeen {display:none;}
{/literal}
</style>
{/if}
{if $product->quantity >= 1}
<style type="text/css">
{literal}
.hideen {display:none;}
{/literal}
</style>
{/if}
```

There can you see where the HTML where will be applied:

```
<button type="submit" name="Submit" class="exclusive">
<span class="btn">
{if $content_only && (isset($product->customization_required) && $product->customization_required)}<em>{l s='Customize'}</em>{else}<em class="hideeen">{l s='Add to cart'}</em>{/if}<em class"hideen">{l s='order'}</em>
</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Are you really distinguishing these two classes by a single character (`hideen` vs `hideeen`)? That's _very_ easy to misread, and it took me way longer than it should have to even understand your question because of it. Consider using something more readable.

Comment: and why have two different style classes for this in the first place? Why not a SINGLE style, and have something more like `<style>.hide { display: {smartycodehere} }</style>` to generate JUST a none/block-type thing?

Comment: you are using same css in both two if conditions..so why are not using only one class??

Comment: readability is relative, what is readable to Sasha may not be readable to you; does not make it wrong.

Comment: @MarcB what do you mean? I don't understand what the code should you'll insert on {smartycodehere}, can you post more clear? 
I want to display one and hide the other (like breakpoints with the @ media on CSS). 

But my first question is, why the "greather than >=" code doesn't work? 

When I try to insert it the page crash..

Comment: You always can use `1 <= something` or `something gt 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the HTML miss the `=` there `<em class"hideen">{l s='order'}</em>`

Answer (score 0):

Smarty uses some kind of xml parser, so code should be valid xml.
GreaterThan sign brakes xml structure.

Best solution is to use `lt`/`gt` functions:

```
{if $product->quantity gt 1}
```

Another options can be:

- Wrap this section with `<![CDATA[`, `]]>` markers.
- Use inverted conditions: `1 <= $q`